# How do I generate and filter on a variable related to relationship variables in cypher/neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a list of Companies and ownership relationships with some strength of ownership variable for each relationship. The basic cypher pattern looks like this:

```
(c:Company)-[:INVESTS_IN {pct:25}]->(oc:Company)
```

... where c is the owning company and owns 25% of oc, the owned company.

In intercorporate investment, any investment below 20% is seen as relatively unimportant, investments between 20% and 50% are assumed to have some influence on the owned company, and any investment over 50% means the owning company controls the owned company (now known as a subsidiary).

I'd like to find which companies any other company controls or influences. The easy cypher is this:

```
match (c:Company)-[rels:INVESTS_IN*..]->(oc:Company)
where ALL (rel in rels WHERE rel.pct > 20)
return c.name, oc.name, extract(x in rels| x.pct) as pcts
```

But that's clumsy. Now I want to look for more hidden ownership, e.g.: Company A owns 10% of Company X, as well as 50% or more of companies B, C, D and E, and each of those companies owns 12% of company X. All that adds up to Company A having a controlling stake (50%+) in company X if it exercises control through all its subsidiaries.

I need a way to identify ownership relationships between companies and sum the final incoming pct values for the owned company (oc), but only if the chains between c and oc all have pct values of 50 or more up until that last relationship. So, I need to filter the relationships based on the pct and then create an ownership variable from the last links in the pathway.

Any pointers or thoughts much appreciated.

Comment: Your math seems flawed. ((50% * (4 * 12%)) + 10%) is only 34%, which is less than 50%. Please either correct your example or clarify the formula you are using.

Comment: This is quite an interesting question, do you have any cypher that you could share to play with as an example to test?

Comment: @cybersam, Sorry, I should have made clear this is about intercorporate investment: 

If company A owns up to 20% of company B, it's considered a financial investment, like if a private individual bought stock. 

Between 20% and 50%, is an "investment in associate", which suggests A is trying to exert some control over B. 

Above 50% is a controlling interest, meaning A can control B's actions.

So, 50% is a cutoff (should be 51%), and means A controls all of 4 companies' 12% ownership of B, or 48%. Adding that to its own 10% stake, means it can control 58% of the shares of B.

Comment: I think you still need to correct the wording in your question. You stated that Company A owns "50% or more of companies B, C, D and E, and each of those companies owns 12% of company X". That is not the same as stating that Company A owns "100% of companies B, C, D and E, and each of those companies owns 12% of company X". That is why I made my initial comment.

Comment: @cybersam, your concerns are noted, but since it doesn't really affect the stuff I'm trying to figure out about cypher, just how to fine tune the formulae later on, I'm not going to change anything. 50% ownership or more, in stock terms, gives majority voting rights, and therefore 100 control.

Comment: @DomWeldon, here's some preliminary code I've put together that (sort of) solves my question:

`match p=(c:Company)-[rels:INVESTS_IN*0..]->(ic:Company)-[lrel:INVESTS_IN]->(oc:Company)
where ALL (rel in rels WHERE rel.pct > 50)
with c, oc, collect(lrel) as ownershipStakes
return c.name, oc.name, reduce(s = 0, x IN ownershipStakes | s + x.pct)
order by c.name`